# How do i effectively change python3 list of lists to golang multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, go, multidimensional-array

This is my python3 code. I am porting my code to golang as its getting famous:

```py
def replacement(parameter: list, value: list, replace_str: str, only = None) -> list:
        c_counter  = []
        returner_list = []
        counter = 0
        length = len(parameter)
        while counter != length:
            parameter_temporary_value = value[counter]
            for index in range(length):
                value[counter] = replace_str
#                if only:
#                    if parameter[index] in only:
#                        c_counter.append(parameter[index] + '=' + value[index])
#                else:
                c_counter.append(parameter[index] + '=' + value[index])

            returner_list.append(c_counter)
            value[counter] = parameter_temporary_value
            counter += 1
            c_counter = []
        #if only:
            # Decreasing repetition of data (optional)
        #    return [x for x in returner_list if replace_str in [y.split('=')[-1] for y in x]]
        #else:
        return returner_list
print(replacement(["A", "B", "C"], ["1", "2", "3"], "REPLACED"))
```

This is the code I wrote

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

func replacement(parameter []string, value []string, replace_str string) [][]string{
    var temporary_counter []string;
    var returner_list [][]string;
    var counter int = 0;
    var length int = len(parameter);
    for {
        if counter == length {
            break
        }
        holder := value[counter];
        for index := 0; index < length; index++ {
            value[counter] = replace_str; //only variable not implemented
            temporary_counter = append(temporary_counter, parameter[index] + value[index])
        }
        returner_list := append(returner_list, temporary_counter)
        value[counter] = holder;
        counter += 1;
        temporary_counter = temporary_counter[:0];
    }
    return returner_list
}
func main(){
    a := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    b := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
    fmt.Println(replacement(a, b, "REPLACED"));
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:18:3: returner_list declared but not used
```

Can anyone help me solve this error? Note the only variable will be implemented later, so dont worry about that.

Comment: What is your original code even supposed to do?

Comment: Replace variable, wait letme update my question

Comment: `returner_list := append(returner_list, temporary_counter)` should be `returner_list = append(returner_list, temporary_counter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to know the scope of variables in Go. In your code, You defined `returner_list` outside the `if` block. And then you want to use it inside this `if` block.But you used `:=`, Go wouldn't use the `returner_list` you defined outside the `if` block but create a local variable in this block.(And that's why your error was: `returner_list declared but not used`)

So if you want to change the variable you have defined.Use `returner_list = append(returner_list, temporary_counter)` instead of `returner_list := append(returner_list, temporary_counter)`

Comment: @DipeshSunrait `'='` is a rune type. You may need to use `parameter[index] + "=" + value[index];`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler way to implement your original code. Might make it easier to port to any other language.

```
def replacement2(ks: list, vs: list, replace_str: str) -> list:
    original_pairs = [f"{k}={v}" for (k, v) in zip(ks, vs)]
    output = []
    for i in range(len(ks)):
        new_pairs = original_pairs[:]  # Copy original,
        new_pairs[i] = f"{ks[i]}={replace_str}"  # replace this index.
        output.append(new_pairs)  # Save new copy.
    return output
```

Or here, an alternate way that does a little extra work but doesn't copy as much:

```
def replacement3(ks: list, vs: list, replace_str: str) -> list:
    output = []
    for i in range(len(ks)):
        output.append(
            [
                f"{k}={replace_str if j==i else v}"
                for j, (k, v) in enumerate(zip(ks, vs))
            ]
        )
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me for improving my function but i cant accept it as answer as its not directly related to my question. Also i needed in golang. jizhihaoSAMA answered in comment